# Cauchy-Goursat Proof

Tags: complex-analysis

I am busy going through the lecture note for the proof of the Cauchy-Goursat Theorem (when the path $\gamma$ traces out a rectangle $\mathscr{R}_0$)and seems to be stuck towards the end.

$\int_{\mathscr{R}_k}f(z)dz = \int_{\mathscr{R}_k}[f(z_0) + f'(z_0)(z-z_0)]dz + \int_{\mathscr{R}_k}s(z - z_0)(z-z_0)dz = 0 + \int_{\mathscr{R}_k}s(z - z_0)(z-z_0)dz$

$k$ is chosen such that the rectangle $\mathscr{R}_k$ ($k^{th}$ subdivided rectangle into four congruent parts) lies inside an open disc $D_r(z_0)$. $f$ is analytic, so $f(z) = f(z_0) + f'(z_0)(z - z_0) + s(z-z_0)(z-z_0)$ where $s(z-z_0) \to 0$ as $z \to z_0$. $r$ was chosen so that $(\forall z \in D_r(z_0))$$(|s(z-z_0)| < A/P^2)$ where $A = |\int_{\gamma}{f(z)dz}|$ and $P = |\mathscr{R}_0|$.

I have two questions:

(1) Why $\int_{\mathscr{R}_k}[f(z_0) + f'(z_0)(z-z_0)]dz = 0$? Well, it said the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus was used, $\mathscr{R}_k$ is closed, but I am not sure how $f(z_0) + f'(z_0)(z-z_0)$ has an antiderivative, is it because $f(z_0)z + f'(z_0)z^2/2 - f'(z_0)z_0z$?

(2) It later says $|\int_{\mathscr{R}_k}f(z)dz| \leq (A/P^2)*(1/2)*|\mathscr{R}_k|^2$ and I don't fully get it. Well, since $\int_{\mathscr{R}_k}f(z)dz = \int_{\mathscr{R}_k}s(z - z_0)(z-z_0)dz$ and $|s(z-z_0)| < A/P^2$, $|\int_{\mathscr{R}_k}s(z - z_0)dz| < (A/P^2)|\mathscr{R}_k|$, but I cannot proceed any further.

Any tip or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes $\int_\gamma (f(z_0)+f'(z_0)(z-z_0))dz =F|_{\gamma(0)}^{\gamma(1)} =F(\gamma(1))-F(\gamma(0)) = 0 $ because the integrand is analytic so it has an analytic anti-derivative, namely $F(z) =C+ f(z_0)z+\frac12 f'(z_0)(z-z_0)^2$.

Comment: @reuns Thank you so much for making this clear, any thoughts on (2)?

Comment: Maybe, since $z$ and $z_0$ lie in $\mathscr{R}_k$, the distance between the two is less than the diagonal of the rectangle, which is clearly less than $|\mathscr{R}_k|/2$?

Comment: Yes if $|g(z)| \le C$ and $\gamma$ is a curve of length $L$ then $|\int_\gamma g(z)dz| \le LC$. And $g(z) = \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$ is locally bounded because $f'(z_0)$ exists.